# Index view doesn't recognize variable from sidebar view

Tags: php, laravel

[image: Error on index view from other view]

When i load my 'index' view it gives me this error:

I need to load categories from DB in the 'side' view which is included in layout. 'Side' view is the sidebar of layout page and those categories are supposed to show on all other views. When i go to '/side' i get properly pulled categories from DB, but when i go to '/index' i get error above.

Here is my code:

```
**Web.php**

Route::get('/index', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/side', 'MovieController@showcat');

**MovieController.php**

public function showcat(){

             $model = new MovieModel();
             $podaciIzBaze = $model->showcat();
             $data = array();
             $data['dt'] = $podaciIzBaze;
             return view('fixed.side', $data); 
    }

**MovieModel.php**

public function showcat(){  
        $query= DB::SELECT("SELECT * FROM categories");
        return $query;
    }

**side.blade.php**

    @foreach($dt as $podatak)
              <li><a href="#">{{ $podatak->catname }}</a></li>
              @endforeach
```

'Side' view is included in layout.blade.php and 'index' view is yield in 'layout' view.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're talking about `/index` but you didn't presented `HomeController` controller

Comment: HomeController is just plain:
  public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }

Comment: You say side view is *included* in the layout. If it gets its variables directly (like in your `showcat()` action), that means layout hasn't got the access to them. Likewise for any other templates extending layout and if I understood you correctly, `index` extends `layout`.

Comment: Yes, index extends layout. So how can i include variable from side view to index view?

Comment: You can either explicitly send it to `index` in the controller or include that variable in layout then pass it from there into side view and index. Variables can't be passed "up" (to parents) or "horizontally" (to siblings), only "down" (to children).